# Automate a deployment task (Use case)

Tags: git, automation, version, devops

What is the best approach to automate a deployment with the following constraints:

- The repository located on bitbucket.

Steps:

1. pull latest changes from the master branch.
2. increment the version using this command "npm version patch".
3. execute build task.
4. push changes into the repository.

Does something like this can achieve what I want ?

```
$ git pull origin master && npm version patch && gulp && git push origin master
```

Comment: All is good, I just need to find a safe way to store credentials of the bitbucket user.

Comment: My question is all about how to make this task in a best approach.

Comment: That is a far too broad question. If you show us your gulpfile and tell us the concrete problems you encounter, you can get an answer.

Comment: Actually it's not related to the gulp APIs. I edited the question. Thank you ^_^

Comment: It's not clear where you want to deploy to